# MDi background image make animated sub form appear slow

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I have a panel and a timer which is helping me to open a form in an animated way.
The panel contains a form.
code is

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel1.Width < 1004)
        {
            panel1.Left -= 50;
            panel1.Width += 50;

        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Code is working perfectly when I click a button to enable the timer **with no background image in the MDI Form**.

But **whenever I put a background image its become slow**. Takes longer time than before. Every Timer interval can be understood. Form appears by shaking.

Is there is any solution? What can be done to avoid this.

Comment: How do You put background image for this form? Where this image is placed and how do you gain access to it?

Comment: I choose BackgroundImage Property from the properties window itself for MDI form

Comment: This image is taken from Resources file of project or loaded from some location in hard drive?